# Why can't I change the directory on my Mac terminal using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Very new to this whole coding thing, and I'm trying to teach myself.

I'm working on Mac OS X Version 10.6.8, using whatever the version of Ruby is installed by default, in Terminal.

I'm trying to change directories, but for some reason, the Terminal ceases to accept any input after that.

I typed in:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

and it just wouldn't let me do anything.

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby?  Are you trying to change directories in Ruby?

Comment: my guess is it did change directories, try typing `ls` after you cd - it should list all of the files and directories on your Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're in IRb when you do this. `cd` is a shell command. IRb is an interactive version of the Ruby programming language, not a sh-style shell. You can't `cd`, `ls`, `chmod` or anything like that, as those are not part of Ruby. You can change the current directory with `Dir.chdir`, but generally you'll want to go to the directory you want to be in and then open Ruby. Trying to use Ruby as an alternative to Bash will be a little awkward.

Comment: You're thinking that `cd ~ /Desktop` is missing the closing `/` for the regex?

Comment: @muistooshort: My thinking precisely.

Answer (score -1):

If you press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (`^D`) in the terminal window do you get something like this?

```
-:1: unterminated string meets end of file
-:1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_END, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tREGEXP_END or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR
```

If so, I'm guessing you typed `ruby` at the command prompt.

Do  `cd ~/Desktop` first, then type `irb` for interactive Ruby which offers [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)

Comment: Don't type `ruby` by itself at all. `irb` is interactive Ruby.

Comment: Updated to state more clearly what I think they did, and what they should do to correct it.

Comment: @theTinMan - Thanks for editing the post. I was unaware of the keyboard tag and the back tick.

Comment: Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox for examples of all sorts of formatting examples.